# Change BaseActivity' Toolbar Title From Child Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a BaseActivity which gets inherited from all the other child activities and in that BaseActivity I set the toolbar:

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(getLayoutId())

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
            supportActionBar?.apply {
                setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(getActivityTitle() != null)
                setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(getActivityTitle() != null)
                getActivityTitle()?.let {
                    this.title = getActivityTitle()
                }
            }
        }
    }


open fun getActivityTitle(): String? = null
```

And on the ChildActitivy I have the following code:

```
    override fun getActivityTitle(): String? {
        return getString(R.string.gen_everyone_is_watching)
    }
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The problem is that I can not display the title when I want to do that in a child activity and the only way I have found to display the title is to not set the toolbar on the BaseActivity. Have you encountered anything similar?

Comment: I can't see any setTitle code in the above snippet for setting title to toobar

Comment: @Nick, are you sure that your **`toolbar`** is not null ?

Comment: `if (toolbar != null) { 
      
toolbar.title = (getActivityTitle() != null)
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}`
remove rest of the statement inside your if condition.

Comment: @VivekMishra this.title = getActivityTitle(), and this = the actionbar

Comment: @JeelVankhede Yes it is not null

Comment: @Nick Are you using kotlin extensions? if yes then can you tell me where your toolbar is loaded, is it in `BaseActivity` or in `ChildActivity`?

Comment: Yes, it is loaded in the base activity and that was the intent in order to set the toolbar in one place. Also when as set the title on the child activity I have tried: supportActionBar.title, activity.title and (activity as BaseActivity).title...None of them worked.

Comment: Can you show your `style.xml` file?